# CreateWindow fails in thread created by _beginthreadex

Tags: c++, multithreading, createwindow

I have a thread function and I create a window from that thread

Whenever I create my thread with `CreateThread()` API, the `CreateWindow()` returns true and it creats the window, BUT if I create my thread using `_beginthreadex`, `CreateWindow()` returns false and it does not create Window

This is how I create threads :

With `CreateThread()`

```
// My Thread Function : HRESULT WINAPI CreateWndForHotkey(LPVOID)
CreateThread(NULL,NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)CreateWndForHotkey,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

With `_beginthreadex()`

```
// My Thread Function : unsigned WINAPI CreateWndForHotkey(LPVOID)
_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &CreateWndForHotkey, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: Can you provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: "If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError. " So what does GetLastError return?

Comment: Child window by any chance? There are tricky rules about doing UI work in a thread.

Comment: @MSalters This is already a child window

Comment: Creating a child window in a different thread than the parent window's thread can cause deadlocks. You don't want to do that.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP But as I said it works when I create my thread using CreateThread()

Comment: @Shahriyar: So? ScottMcP is right: it **can** cause deadlocks. He didn't say it **will** cause deadlocks.